# How to call method with View Parameter on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, methods, view, parameters

I want to call this method

```
public void openButton(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

from simple method like this

```
public void simple(){
    openButton();
}
```

but I can't do it because openButton needs one parameter View. How?

Comment: The `openButton()` method is not making use of the `view` parameter, calling it simply as `openButton(null)` should work ?

Comment: If this was just for testing purpose, then the way you invoked is fine, else you need to follow the procedure mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, with the code that you provided, you usually use some sort of an `onCickListener`.

Open your XML file, and add `android:onClick="openButton"` to the button that you want to call that method. So your XML for the button will look something like this:

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Click me!"
   . . . 
   android:onClick="openButton" />
```

That will automatically call that method and pass in a view.

The other option, as BatScream mentioned in the comments, is to just pass in `null`, as you aren't using the view anyway. HOWEVER, this is bad practice - it'll work this time, but in general, you should follow the system that Android uses. Just go with an `onClick` in the XML.

---

If you HAVE to use `simple` the way it is, do it this way:

```
public void simple(){
    openButton(null);
}
```

Comment: I know, but i just want to start activity from method simple(). How ?

Comment: @user2565280 added it. Same thing that BatScream said in the comments

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
 button.performClick();
```

assuming `openButton()` is the method assigned to `button`s `onClick`. Meaning, somewhere in your xml you probably have a `Button` with `android:onClick="openButton"`. Then if you have that `Button` instantiated and assigned to the variable `button`, calling the `View`'s `performClick()` method would call `openButton()`

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just pass the view in arguments.

**Way 1:** if you are calling `openButton()` method from layout file then, simply call method the following way by applying onClick attribute

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Go to next screen"
   . . . 
   android:onClick="openButton" />
```

**Way 2:** if you are trying to call it from button's onclick by setting OnClickListener, then, simply pass the view you are getting inside `OnClickListener`'s `onClick(View view)` method as follows:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       openButton(view);
    }

});
```